# OSX set "Date Created" from filename

Tags: macos, loops, date, screenshot

I have a folder filled with screenshots from World of Warcraft and I have lost the original date stamps (date created metadata).

The good news is that all files is named systematically with dates

WoWScrnShot_123109_224259.jpg

WoWScrnShot_092510_213950.jpeg

WoWScrnShot_041813_183548.tga

WoWScrnShot_011315_132530.png

So it's
WoWScrnShot_MMDDYY_HHMMSS.filetype

I want a script that loops through all the pictures in my screenshots folder and set the meta data accordingly.

Note: the files are in jpg/jpeg/tga/png

Comment: What language are you using?  Have you looked at docs for `- setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:`?

Comment: I have looked into the Terminal commando touch and SetFile and I have used it for a single file succesfully. But I have 14000+ screenshots. And in order to speed it up I want to write a script that grabs the date and time from each filename and loop each one and set the date and time accordingly.

Comment: I kinda know how this would look like. I need to put the filename in a variable and use that to set the date and time. and make a loop for all files in a folder with some criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really ugly bash-script that I wrote a while back for the exact same purpose that I just modified a little so it will work on OS X. Hope it works for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/Path/To/Screenshots/*
for f in $FILES
do
    month="$(echo $f | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | awk '{gsub("/Path/To/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_", "");print}' | awk '{print substr($0,0,2)}')"
    day="$(echo $f | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | awk '{gsub("/Path/To/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_", "");print}' | awk '{print substr($0,3,2)}')"
    year="$(echo $f | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | awk '{gsub("/Path/To/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_", "");print}' | awk '{print substr($0,5,2)}')"
    hour="$(echo $f | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | awk '{gsub("/Path/To/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_", "");print}' | awk '{print substr($0,8,2)}')"
    minute="$(echo $f | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | awk '{gsub("/Path/To/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_", "");print}' | awk '{print substr($0,10,2)}')"
    second="$(echo $f | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' | awk '{gsub("/Path/To/Screenshots/WoWScrnShot_", "");print}' | awk '{print substr($0,12,2)}')"
    echo $f
    SetFile -d "$month/$day/$year $hour:$minute:$second" $f
    SetFile -m "$month/$day/$year $hour:$minute:$second" $f
done
```